# Disable all js functions after one of them runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs when certain keys are pressed and I can reuse how many time I want. Then there is another function that runs when when certain key combo is pressed- the idea is that it should run once.

What I want to do is the whole code should stop working when second function finishes running and maybe forces uses to refresh page or refresh page itself.
So is there a way to disable the whole script?

Comment: you need to post a code

Comment: https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/dVzRPq
Code is here you can check it out

Comment: add the code to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `.off()` chained to `jQuery()` with multiple selectors passed to the function to remove attached events from one or more matched elements

```
$("#second").on("event" /* "keydown" */, function() {
  // do stuff
  $("#first, #second").off("keydown")
})
```